# Heatmap generation in r

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap

I need some suggestions regarding the heatmap generation with `heatmap.2` in R. I have a matrix for gene expression values which has 15,616 rows and 27 columns for generating the heatmap. The problem is the code I am using is creating the heatmap but the visualization is not good as the matrix size is large. So can you give me suggestions as to how to get a proper heatmap out of such a huge matrix? I am attaching the command I am using to generate the heatmap and the warnings I am receiving. It would be great if someone can help me with the adjustment of the dimensions to generate a proper heatmap.

```
color <- colorpanel(100,low="blue",mid="white",high="red")

heatmap.2(data4,Rowv="none",col=color,trace='none',
        density.info="none",scale="row",labRow=NULL,
        lmat=rbind( c(0, 3), c(2,1), c(0,4) ), lhei=c(1.5, 4, 2 ))
```

Warning message:

> In heatmap.2(data4, Rowv = "none", col = color, trace = "none",  :
>         Discrepancy: Rowv is FALSE, while dendrogram is `column'. Omitting row dendogram.

It would be nice to have suggestions regarding a proper visualization of the heatmap with the colour key panel small and the image more distinct on columns which are my conditions and the image shifted towards a bit right as when I am generating it is a bit shifted to left. I am unable to upload the image of the heatmap as I am new to the forum and don't have that privilege. I am unable to judge the appropriate values for the matrix while generating the heatmap.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too vague to get a detailed answer, however, here are a couple of things to help you out:

1. Colours. Typically, you want the `mid` point to be zero. So you probably want to try something like:

   ```
   breaks = c(seq(min(data4), 0, length.out=128), 
              seq(0, max(data4), length.out=128))
   heatmap.2(..., col=bluered(255), breaks=breaks,...)
   ```
2. Your matrix is too large - well make it smaller. Typically, only "differentially expressed genes" are shown in the heatmap. So select the top 50 genes or so, and plot them.

Comment: These are the expression value (FPKM) generated from the cuffdiff output with 27 different conditions and then I have generated a matrix for all the conditions with the expression values with the genes with status OK Note :Can be one of OK (test successful), NOTEST (not enough alignments for testing), LOWDATA (too complex or shallowly sequenced), HIDATA (too many fragments in locus), or FAIL, when an ill-conditioned covariance matrix or other numerical exception prevents testing. So now I have a matrix of all the genes which have properly mapped with the expression values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't help you resolve your issue with `heatmap.2`, as I myself found it does not perform overly well with specific tasks and data sets.

I would recommend looking at `ComplexHeatmaps` which might potentially be more suited to such large volumes of data. It also has extensive supporting documents on how to use it that can be [found here](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/index.html).

As of writing this, the following command with get you the very most up-to-date version from [GitHub](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap), though a stable version is available on [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html).

Most Recent (you must use `force = TRUE`):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap", force = TRUE)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
```

Stable:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("ComplexHeatmap", version = "3.8")
```

I know it is sub-optimal to be told to change packages but it is a more comprehensive tool AND is very well explained in the support file. The creator [jokergoo](https://github.com/jokergoo) also appears to be highly attentive. Moreover, I am not sure how effectively / easily `heatmap.2` can be coerced into displaying what I assume would be 421,632 data cells. I have just switched to `ComplexHeatmaps` and find it to be very thorough.

I'm going to leave some sample images below to show you the scope of `ComplexHeatmaps` given the amount of data you appear to have.

Simple heatmap example (doesn't have to be flashy):

[image: Simple_Heatmap_Example]

Complex heatmap example (i):

[image: Complex_Example(i)]

Complex heatmap example (ii):

[image: Complex_Example_(ii)]

Comment: Why is ```ComplexHeatmaps``` potentially more suited to such large volumes of data？

Comment: I'm afraid I can't expand as I haven't looked at the package in two years. I simply recall that it seemed more geared towards complex data sets than other packages I had trialled.